# Import app foreign key model class in another app model

Tags: django, model, migrate

I know there are other similar questions, but I have a specific case:

Right now there are two apps:
-prev_app
-new_app

prev_app contains a "product" model. 
new_app contains "store" and "contract" model.
"store" model has a manytomanyfield to "product" model
"contract" is a intermediary model for "store" and "product"

..
.

So now what I want to do is to put that "product" model into the new_app, (so all related models are in one app) but I just don't know how to proceed with the migrations.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put [`db_table`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#db-table) to your model and move it wherever you want. it refers then always to that old db table and you dont need any migrations for your new app.

```
class Product(models.Model):
   class Meta: 
     db_table = 'oldapp_tablename'
```

just be careful that imports should be adjusted according to new layout.

Comment: I tried and it worked. But afterwards, I added a field into one of the models which forced me to do a migration. And here lies the problem, once i migrated, the log says "django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "prevapp_product" already exists". Looks like the migration first deleted the model in the prev_app and then when creating the model "product" in the new_app something went wrong, and in the operations it's already stated to use 'prevapp_product' table. Any clues?

Comment: At the beginning, the db_table='oldapp_tablename' helped me, but in order to go on with the migrations, I had to take it out and load data from the previos table into the new one generated by the migrations.